# jQuery - check if the element is visible and fade in

Tags: jquery

I have a `<div>` element on my page (let's say it has `.myelement` class). I have a third-party script that manipulates the element and can change its visibility style attribute to "`visibility: visible`".

I need to check if .myelement's visibility is `:visible`, and if it is, then trigger jQuery `.fadeIn()` function.

Answer (score 8):

I think you mean check if element is visible and if **not**, fade it in. There is no point in fading in an element that is already visible on the page. If that is the case you should do something like this:

```
var $element = $('.myelement');

if (!$element.is(':visible')) {
    $element.fadeIn();
}
```

or

```
if ($element.is(':hidden')) {
    // your logic goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.css("property")` function to extract the style value belong to the `visible` property then do a normal compare and call the `fadeIn` if the condition evaluates to true,

```
var elem = $(".myelement");
if(elem.css("visibility") === "visible"){
  elem.fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: I thought fadeToggle has a switch parameter initially. but it doesn't. so reverted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery css function

```
//first cache your element 
var elm = $(".myelement");//better to use an id if you are targeting a specific element 

 if (elm.css("visibility") === "visible"){
  elm.fadeIn();
 }else{
   elm.fadeOut();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think before start the fadeIn animation you have to set display:none at the element, so fadeIn function will make appear softly your div.
In jquery you can do it using hide()

try this snippet, for me works

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var $myel = $(".myelement");  
   if ($myel.css("visibility") === "visible"){
     $myel.hide();
     $myel.fadeIn("slow");
   }
});
```